# Why `ep_rew_mean` much larger than the reward evaluated by the `evaluate_policy()` fuction

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines, policy-gradient-descent

I write a custom gym environment, and trained with PPO provided by stable-baselines3. The `ep_rew_mean` recorded by tensorboard is as follow:

[the ep_rew_mean curve for total 100 million steps, each episode has 50 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43VZM.png)

As shown in the figure, the reward is around 15.5 after training, and the model converges. However, I use the function `evaluate_policy()` for the trained model, and the reward is much smaller than the `ep_rew_mean` value. The first value is mean reward, the second value is std of reward:

> 4.349947246664763 1.1806464511030819

the way I use function `evaluate_policy()` is:

```
mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=10000)
```

According to my understanding, the initial environment is randomly distributed in an area when using `reset()` fuction, so there should not be overfitting problem.

I have also tried different learning rate or other parameters, and this problem is not solved.

I have checked my environment, and I think there is no error.

I have searched on the internet, read the doc of stable-baselines3 and issues on github, but did not find the solution.

Comment: was your env wrapped with a Monitor or any other rescaling wrappers during the training? SB3 often does it in background before training, while `evaluate_policy` takes unscaled values from `env.step`.

Comment: Thanks to your reply. My env is not wrapped with a monitor. I didn't notice this, I will check it later. So the `evaluate_policy` gets the true value of reward I get from the model?

Comment: I have wrapped my env with a monitor, and retrained the model, didn't notice the reward was rescaled. wrap a monitor before using `evaluate_policy` doesn't change the reward as well. My env have fixed number of steps per episode, so I guess the monitor is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate_policy` has `deterministic` to `True` by default (https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/common/evaluation.html).

If you sample from the distribution during training, it may help to evaluate the policy without it selecting the actions with an `argmax` (by passing in `deterministic=False`).

Comment: Could be the case if author had observed the opposite, so that a reward by `evaluate_policy ` would have been too good. But it is the other way round. I would run `evaluate_policy` with `return_episode_rewards=True` and see how rewards behave

Comment: @tacon I set `deterministic=False`, the reward increased a little, but still far less than the reward in training. @gehirndienst I think the `return_episode_rewards=True` has the same result of wrapping a monitor.